# Changing wo-rds into words without dash

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to replace words at the end of the line separated with "-" like:

```
blah blah bl-
ah blah
```

into just:

```
blah blah
blah blah
```

Should I just find and replace "-" with ""? (This would replace wanted dashes as well.)

Edit for Hambone:
The strings are something like this:

```
"prior permis- sion of the publishers"
```

Comment: The example you show us has a SPACE following the dash. The "find" Hambone suggests does not include a space.  Perhaps if you add a space you'll get more "hits"? I suspect those will be the ones you want as this approach will allow Word to break the word as "hyphenated". The person who did this probably didn't know how to correctly use Word's built-in hyphenation feature...

Comment: @cindy It was not done on Word. It was converted to PDF document than to a Word doc from a program called Quicksilver. That's probably what's causing the issues. Since I am running several macros on Word, I wanted to convert hyphens into regulars but I will try Hambone's method again.

Comment: Interesting... It's possible that the ANSI character code(s) involved aren't the same as those used in the code sample you got. Let us know if it still doesn't work and we can investigate those characters more closely...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you certainly **can** use VBA, you actually don't even need it for this.  Microsoft Word support regular expressions in the find/replace dialog.

To enable regex, just ensure the "Use WildCards" flag is turned on in the find/replace dialog.  From there, you can use Regex.  Here is an example of something that would replace a series of characters followed by a hyphen and another series of characters to the hyphen-less version:

[image]

If you are not familiar with Regex:

- ( ) captures a match
- [ ] means "any of these"
- \1 = returns the first match (first group of parentheses)

If, for example, you wanted letters and numbers, it would look like this:

```
(a-zA-Z0-9)-(a-zA-Z0-9)
```

Also, if you really want VBA for this, you can either use the VBScript Regular Expression library, or you can record these steps as a macro and clean it up to suit your needs.

Comment: This would still catch "wanted hyphens" as well as unwanted ones.

Comment: I have just tried it out and instead of it returning hundreds of replacements, it returned just 4. Not even the first hyphenated word was corrected.

Comment: Is it possible it wasn't really a hyphen?  I know Word frequently autocorrects my hyphens to an extended Unicode dash.  Also, can you post some example of actual strings that you want replaced?